# read image from a file using pure c/c++

Tags: image

is there a library with source can be used to read images with different formats?

The library:

1. is very thin, not like OpenCV with so much code,
2. is able to read bmp, png, jpeg files,
3. is self-contained,
4. does not depend on operating system,
5. is written using pure c/c++.
6. is open souce.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would suggest **CImg** - it is a single header file with no libraries to link. It is [here](http://cimg.eu).

If you add the following flags to your compilation command, it uses its own built-in routines rather than depending on ImageMagick, for example:

```
gcc -Dcimg_use_png -Dcimg_use_jpeg -Dcimg_use_tiff -Dcimg_use_curl ...
```

Additionally, if you define `cimg_display` as one of the following values, you can get certain advantages:

- 0 - you cannot natively display anything, but you do not require X11, or GDI to compile and link against - this is great on embedded hardware
- 1 - you can use X11 for displaying images easily
- 2 - you can use Windows GDI to display images.

You can find related questions/answers on StackOverflow by putting `[cimg]` as well as any other terms you want to search for in the search box at top-right of this screen.

---

Another option would be **libvips** - it is significantly faster and lower memory overhead than **CImg**, but maybe not as pure C++ (IMHO).

It is [here](https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips). You can find related questions/answers on StackOverflow by putting `[vips]` in the search box at top-right of this screen.